# How to load a custom UITableViewCell without using nib name

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I'm designing my application,As per the design tableView should load any custom cell based on the reusable identifier.

From webservice tableView will get will get list of reusable identifiers and  tableView will load all cells as per the identifier.

Here is my `cellForRowAtIndex` method

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[_cardsIdentifier objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];//_cardsIdentifier is array of identifiers 
    if (cell == nil) {
        // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:[_cardsIdentifier objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] owner:self options:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",cell.reuseIdentifier);
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


    return cell;
}
```

As one can see i'm using same identifier for nib name as well.
It will work fine when reusable identifier and nib name is same,but it will crash if nib name is different  from reusable identifier.

**Can anyone suggest how can i remove this dependency of nib name.**

Answer (score 1):

Register your cell class

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]
       forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

And in your cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

Comment: CustomCell is not known ..the only information about cell we have is identifier

Comment: Well, it is because is the cell is initialize with the default style. You can also initialize it with other style, check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewCellStyle).

Or you can use your own design by subclassing the UITableViewCell without nib and create your on design.

Answer (score 0):

You can set identify in .xib files.